# Disable emails turned into links but keep urls turned into links

Tags: emails, navigation

Some users on social sites still enter their email addresses on comment fields.
I'm trying to prevent spammers from harvesting them by replacing the @ character with a graphic. That's really easy to do using the smiley module.

However, I use the text filter option "Convert URLs into links" which turns the email into a mailto link. The smiley filter now breaks the HTML.

I would like to not turn emails into links but keep turning urls into links.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to creat your own input filter. Do a PREG and obfuscate the email address.  Assign this filter to your input formats, and make sure it runs before the URL-to-link one.

Comment: thanks. I don't think I could obfuscate it with a graphic if it gets turned into a link afterwards. I could replace @ with &#64; but but that could be hacked easily

Comment: Definitely, a custom input filter is by far the easiest solution

Comment: @MotoTribe If you obfuscate it before the URL-to-link  filter runs, then it shouldn't get turned into a link.  Look at the code for [_filter_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/_filter_url/7).  If the "@" isn't there,  then it' won't match.

Answer (score 0):

Spamfree email module replaces email address with mailto links and obfuscates to js code for js supporting browsers and to image for non js browser thus preventing email harvest bots.

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/abhiklpm/2465593